# Is it possible to conditionally format one cell with a databar based on a value in another cell?

Tags: excel

I can do conditional formatting of one cell based on another, no problems, but that only allows me to make simple formatting selections (Like color, font, etc).

What I'm really after is that I have a number in cell A1, and I would like to place a DATABAR in cell A1 that uses cell B1 as the value for purposes of drawing the databar.

From what I can tell, I can ONLY draw the databar in a cell based on the actual value in that cell.

Is that right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is a long standing one but as far as I can tell, this just isn't possible as of Excel 2010. Databars only draw based on the content of the cell they're in.